# Como agregar columnas a partir de valores de una fila?

Tags: sql, diseño

necesito hacer una aplicación que me permita llevar un registro de los resultados de Competencias de Pesca y Caza. Para esta problemática diseñé la siguiente base de datos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debo generar la siguiente tabla:
[image: Una tabla con Nombre,Club, puntajes y la suma del puntaje total]

no se alcanza a distinguir muy bien pero las columnas serian un número de ranking, el club, los puntajes, y el total de los puntajes.
Y actualmente consigo mostrar esto:

[image: Una tabla con mobre, club y puntaje total]
Con la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT concat(PE.nombre," ",PE.apellidoPaterno) as Nombre, 
       CL.nombre as Club, 
       SUM(PC.puntaje) as 'Puntaje Total' 
       from persona PE 
       join club CL 
            on CL.id_club=PE.id_club 
       join personacomp PC 
            on PE.id_persona=PC.id_persona 
       join competencia CO 
            on PC.id_competencia=CO.id_competencia 
       where PC.id_categoria=1 
             and year(CO.fecha)=2017 
       group by PE.id_persona;
```

**Se pueden agregar las filas de los puntajes de la tabla PersonaComp correspondiestes a cada persona como columnas al select de arriba?**
[image: Tabla que deseo conseguir]

Estoy atento a cualquier duda, y retroalimentación sobre el diseño de la base de datos.

### UPDATE ##

**Ahora consigo mostrar la siguiente tabla:**
[image: Tabla con columnas para cada puntaje pero con valores null]
**Utilizando la siguiente consulta:**

```
SELECT concat(PE.nombre," ",PE.apellidoPaterno) as Nombre,  
    case when PC.id_competencia =1 THEN PC.puntaje END 'Puntaje 1' ,   
    case when PC.id_competencia =2 THEN PC.puntaje END 'Puntaje 2',  
    case when PC.id_competencia=3 THEN PC.puntaje END 'Puntaje 3'  
    from persona PE  
    join personacomp PC  
        on PE.id_persona=PC.id_persona  
    where PC.id_categoria=1;
```

**Se puede obtener esta tabla?**
[image: tabla sin los null]

### UPDATE 2 ##

Gracias a guido por informarme, ahora está disponible este recurso para testear:
[pagina para testear sql](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9c1695/1/0)

Comment: Y tienes que generar tantas columnas como `id_competencia` tengas? No sabes de antemano cuáles son esos ID?

Comment: Así es, la cantidad de competencias pueden variar cada año.

Comment: podrias crear tus tablas aqui para ir probando http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: @guido ok, las creo y comento

Comment: @Guido http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9c1695/1/0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**José Gonzáles** del slack de proin chile encontró una solución: https://gist.github.com/Deku/6f58f86f345c55c7aeff2a7123d2e883
Y **Francisco Ignacio Contreras** del grupo de Programadores CL, también:
sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9c1695/62
muchas gracias a todos.

Comment: Agrega la parte importante del enlace, si este deja de funcionar esta ya no serìa valiosa para la comunidad, revisa [answer], saludos.

Answer (score 1):

use un pivot de las columnas solo faltaria ejecutar el string xd me da un error pero la idea basica ya esta http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9c1695/24

Comment: Hola Guido, Francisco Ignacio Contreras del grupo de Programadores CL, encontro una solución. Te la comparto, para que la veas. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9c1695/62