# Como utilizar un prepared statement de mysql en WPF

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, prepared-statements

estoy agregando columnas dinamicamente a partir de filas  con el siguiente prepared statement en mysql.

```
SET @sql = null;
SELECT 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
        'SUM(IF(PC.id_competencia='
        ,PC.id_competencia
        ,',PC.puntaje,0) ) AS Puntaje_'
        ,PC.id_competencia
    )
) into @sql
FROM 
persona PE
Join personacomp PC on PE.id_persona=PC.id_persona
where pc.id_categoria=1;
select @sql;
SET @sql =CONCAT(
            'SELECT concat(PE.nombre," ",PE.apellidoPaterno) as Nombree,',@sql,
            ', SUM(PC.puntaje) AS \'Puntaje Total\' from persona PE
            join personacomp PC on PE.id_persona=PC.id_persona
            where PC.id_categoria=1
            Group By Nombree');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Esta es la tabla que genero:

[image: Tabla que genero a partir del prepared statement]

**Mi pregunta sería cómo puedo ejecutar este prepared statement para llenar un DataGrid con la tabla generada?**

### EDIT ##

mi conexion la hago con una instancia MysqlConnection, de la siguiente manera:

```
            string conexString = "SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=pyc;UID=root;PASSWORD=****";
            MySqlConnection conex = new MySqlConnection(conexString);
```

Comment: La pregunta esta mal hecha. Depende tu metodo de conexion a la base de datos es como haces el prepare. No es lo mismo con EF que directamente. Como estas accediendo a la BD?

Comment: Editado @gbianchi

Comment: y como estas ejecutando la query? que tipo de objeto usas?

Comment: Hola mi intencion es ejecutarla de una manera similar a esto https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.prepare(v=vs.110).aspx (no se como ejecutar este tipos de consultas por eso el titulo de mi pregunta) pero no se como adaptar este metodo

Comment: Me parece que tenes una confusion. ahi tenes dos consultados, cual de las dos queres preparar? Las consultas se preparan para "precompilarlas"y de esa forma que la BD no tenga que hacer un explain plan de cada ejecucion. Si es una sola ejecucion lineal, no tiene sentido. Ademas cual de las dos consultas de ahi arriba queres preparar?

Comment: Es que la parte de arriba agrega columnas dinamicamente (digamos que si hay 3 filas en una tabla, va a concatenar 3 veces   'SUM(IF(PC.id_competencia='
        ,PC.id_competencia
        ,',PC.puntaje,0) ) AS Puntaje_'
        ,PC.id_competencia)   y despues la inserto en otra consulta. @gbianchi

Comment: Para que tengas una mejor idea te comparto mi problema inicial, https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/129158/como-agregar-columnas-a-partir-de-valores-de-una-fila  @gbianchi

Comment: Ok. entiendo, lo que no entiendo es para que necesitas el prepare.. asi como armas tu query en Mysql, deberias armarlo en C#, o llamar a un store procedure. Entiendo tu problema, no se si esta sea la solucion correcta. Estas tratando de solucionar un problema de la vista en la DB, y mas justamente que lo estas mostrando del lado de la vista, quien tiene mas facilidad para procesar estas cosas sin hacer este tipo de enjambre en las consultas...

Comment: Bueno, intentare cambiar el enfoque entonces, para sulocionar este problema en la vista. Gracias por tu tiempo

Comment: De nada.. creo que si cambias el enfoque de tu pregunta a mostrar tu tabla de origen y como queres que quede la view, y probamos desde ahi, vamos a llegar mas lejos.